# How to control which element gets the scrollbar?

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

Suppose you have a HTML document like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #a{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #b{
            height: 10000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="a">
        <div id="b">
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A scrollbar appears, at least for me on Chrome 42.0.2311.135. But I have overflow set to hidden on the parent element to the element that takes up the space. Shouldn't this hide the scrollbar? After a closer look it looks like the scrollbar is on the html element. If you set overflow to hidden on the html element, the scrollbar disappears.

Why has the scrollbar appeard on the html element? And how do you control which element it appears on?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control your appearance is if you use css for html code, and then you can set the elements visible or hidden, like this:

```
a{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

after this your `div` that was tagged with "a" will be invisible.

BTW you can do it in html also:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1.visible {
    visibility: visible
}

h1.hidden {
    visibility: hidden
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="a">This is a visible heading</h1>
<h1 class="b">This is an invisible heading</h1>
<p>Notice that the invisible heading still takes up space.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't possibly been that unclear: As stated in the title, I want to know how to control which element gets the scrollbar, not how to hide an element.

Comment: Ah sorry, for example u can do like this:
<div id="" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">anything</div>

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more fiddling around, I managed to find the problem. The problem is that the #a div tag doesn't have a height. Then it will just expand to make space for the #b div tag. The limit first comes at the HTML tag, which has the same height as the window, and that's why the scrollbar appears there.